# Heroku won't upload recent changes(works locally though)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, ruby-on-rails-4

Everything loads properly locally but Heroku for some reason won't upload my latest changes, it shows an older version of what I'm working on. When I used:

```
   $ Heroku logs --tail
```

I found this error in there:

```
   ←[33m2014-01-23T23:56:04.974299+00:00 heroku[router]:←[0m at=error code=H10 desc
   ="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=omr-pinterestingx.herokuapp.com request_id
   =ffc60e1c-0ffa-4255-b65f-f756b8518a9d fwd="108.227.81.48" dyno= connect= service
   = status=503 bytes= 
   ←[33m2014-01-23T23:56:10.559839+00:00 heroku[router]:←[0m at=error code=H10 desc
   ="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=omr-pinterestingx.herokuapp.com request_id
   =59e9b60a-bec4-4af4-937c-f8bae39562ac fwd="108.227.81.48" dyno= connect= service
   = status=503 bytes=
   ←[33m2014-01-23T23:56:14.323812+00:00 heroku[router]:←[0m at=error code=H10 desc
   ="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=omr-pinterestingx.herokuapp.com request_id
   =5f5402a3-00dd-4b60-abdf-bfa71fa7bc72 fwd="108.227.81.48" dyno= connect= service
   = status=503 bytes=
   ←[33m2014-01-23T23:56:23.453814+00:00 heroku[router]:←[0m at=error code=H10 desc
   ="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=omr-pinterestingx.herokuapp.com request_id
   =75220541-da5d-419f-922a-2316cd6d33dd fwd="108.227.81.48" dyno= connect= service
   = status=503 bytes=
```

I have no idea what this means, is there a problem with my Heroku configuration?

Answer (score 0):

Without more details on the changes, it is hard to say why your latest version crashed on deployment. A common cause is forgetting your database migration. Have you tried this?

`heroku run rake db:migrate`

Another common problem is forgetting to commit and push *Gemfile* and *Gemfile.lock*.

Or maybe, since you're developing on Windows, follow the instructions [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/bundler-windows-gemfile) to deal with the Gemfile issues that arise when deploying a Ruby project generated on Windows. You can also try deleting these lines (or similar) from your *Gemfile.lock*:

```
PLATFORMS
  x86-mingw32
```

Otherwise, scroll up in the logs to see if you can spot a stack trace or a sneaky line like "Missing gem."

Comment: Yes, that is not the problem. What other information would help you in diagnosing the problem?

Comment: Without more details, I can only throw out random guesses like a game of Charades. See edit.

Comment: Right now when I run a heroku run rake db:migrate I get the following   "Running `rake db:migrate` attached to terminal... up, run.2055" In the past when I've tried it I know that it skips my gemfile.lock because it says its already generated in windows.. Perhaps that's a problem?

Comment: I went through that document, it didn't really say anything I could do :[ Damn, I'm on the very last step, just need to figure this out & I'm done!

Comment: Offered one last bit of hope.

Comment: Haha okay, do you suggest I do a heroku restart, would that allow me to start over?

Comment: I don't want to lose all my work, I tried it and it didn't do much. I'm thinking of deleting my heroku and re-installing.. I hope that doesn't cause any other problems...

Comment: Sometimes after doing a `git rebase` or editing the previous commit, I have to use `git push -f heroku master` to force heroku to accept the modified git repo. Also, if you don't have users on your site, deleting the heroku app from the settings page and then re-creating it with `heroku create my-new-app` takes only a minute.